# Updating Waitbar throws error while using matlabpool

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, matlabpool

I'm currently working in Matlab and for the first time I'm trying parallel processing. My code works just fine until I add `matlabpool('open',4);` at the top of my code and `matlabpool('close');` at the bottom.

If I add these two lines all of my CPU-Cores are at 100% workload (like it was intended) and my code still works exept the waitbar I implemented inside a parfor-loop.

The code looks ruffly like this:

```
matlabpool('open',4);

global bar;
bar = waitbar(0, 'Waitbar');


parfor i=1:1000

    //working code

    try
        waitbar(UPDATED_VALUE, bar, UPDATED_STRING);
    end
end

try
    close(bar);
end

//display results


matlabpool('close');
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported under the -nodisplay and -noFigureWindows startup options. For more information, see "Changes to -nodisplay and -noFigureWindows Startup Options" in the MATLAB Release Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run  web('http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/br5ktrh-1.html#br5ktrh-3', '-browser')
In uitools\private\warnfiguredialog at 26
In waitbar at 38
In montecarlo>(parfor body) at 41
In parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general at 891
In remoteParallelFunction at 28
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing you did 'wrong' was to use a waitbar inside a parfor loop haha. But seriously I'm afraid that's because iterations are not executed in order inside a parfor loop so using a regular waitbar is prohibited because of the way information is shared between the Matlab client and the workers executing the loop. Even if you did not write `matlabpool('open',4)` MATLAB would have opened it so the problem is really the fact that the waitbar is in a parfor loop.

As a workaround you might want to look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24594-parfor-progress-monitor) submission form the File Exchange. It was written by Edric Ellis who works at The Mathworks so I would trust his program :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: The strange thing is that whithout these two lines my code works without any error and the waitbar gets updated as planned. The bad thing is just that only 2 Cores are under workload.

But anyway, I will look at the submission you posted.